# How to update images while I change the page?

Tags: reactjs

I have displayed some objects which contains pictures in it. When I try to change the page the written data like the name for example updates correctly on the other hand the picture stays the same

I tried placing an imageHash into the url so it updates the state.

```
state =
{
imageHash = Date.now()
}
return (
            <div>
                {mediaId.media && mediaId.media.map(photo => (
                    <img src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/media/${photo.id}?${imageHash}`} alt={`media${photo.id}`}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
```

I need the corresponding photo to show.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or equivalent?

Comment: there are about 3 components connected

Comment: I understand, but it's very hard to debug something like this without have complete access. My recommendation is that you build a fiddle as simple as possible. You might even stumble upon a solution when doing so because sometimes the answer reveals itself when you isolate an issue like that.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6naael @AdamGerthel

Comment: The sample doesn't work since it attempts to load data from your local server. Any way: You are setting the state on `componentDidMount()` but not when the prop has changed. You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` (or equivalent) in order to update the component state when the props have changed.

Comment: @AdamGerthel UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id){
            this.setState({
                id: nextProps.id,
                imageHash: nextProps.imageHash
            });
        }
        this.loadData()
    } this is what I am trying to do but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own.

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id) {
            this.setState({
                id: nextProps.id,
                imageHash: nextProps.imageHash
            });
        }
        setImmediate(() => this.loadData());
    }
```

It checks for props changes and if there are any it immediately loads the data with the new props.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated in latest React versions but I haven't yet looked into what the replacement is, that's why I recommended it. You should find the new way of doing this if you have the time.

Comment: Also, unless you need it for some other reason, the imageHash isn't required for the image to be updated (from a React perspective) now that you've gotten it working. The problem with the component was that you used a state but didn't update the state when the props changed. Therefor it never changed. When I think about it, the best solution for this would be to just make a stateless component instead. You don't need a state for anything in this component (as far as I can tell).

Comment: You are right about the imageHash. the other part I ll see what I can do. Thanks